# Bind NSTextfieldCell value to first object of an array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, binding, nstextfieldcell

I'm using cocoa binding to bind a NSTextFieldCell value to a controller's dictionnary streamDict.

If i use the model key path "self.streamDict.urls.firstObject.url" it failed !

It's ok if i use the model key path "self.streamDict.url" but that not what i want.

How can i bind the NSTextFieldCell value to the first object of my array "urls" ?

The streamDict :

[image: StreamDict NSDictionnary]

Binding :

[image: Binding details]

Comment: What was the specific nature of the failure? Something more than just the exclamation point in the Model Key Path field? (That's just a warning.)

Comment: App crash : [<__NSArrayM 0x600000046b10> addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:] is not supported. Key path: firstObject.url